# Primary School book about a blue virtual creature called something like "ZipBuzz" and a villain program who pretended to be the Help program

Tags: identification-request

Hoping you can help me identify a book that I first read in primary/elementary school (early 2000s).

I believe it had two children as main  characters, and they were sucked into a computer program that they'd been using at school. One part of the program was blue and called something along the lines of "ZipBuzz" and helped them. Another was the antagonist who I believe masqueraded as the Help program to trick the children's teacher.

The culmination of the book was a competition to list as many words as they could, and "ZipBuzz" could only say the two words that comprised his name and his name itself, which they argued was a word.

Comment: "FizzBuzz" is a common term in computer teaching